# Alternating Variables in SCSS

Tags: css, sass

I want to alternate which variable group that gets used, based on a class on the HTML tag. So I want something like this.

SCSS variable groups:

```
.pink {
  $accent: pink;
}

.green {
  $accent: green;
}

.orange {
  $accent: orange;
}
```

Specify which variable group to use:

```
<html class="pink">
```

HTML File:

```
<section class="accent"></section>
```

Section Styling:

```
section.accent {
  background:$accent;
}
```

So in this example, the section would have a pink background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  This is not possible.  Sass is compiled to CSS, and the CSS is served to the user.  Sass has no idea about how the document is structured.

Your example would have to be written something like this in order for it to work:

```
section.accent {
    .orange & {
        background: orange;
    }

    .pink & {
        background: pink;
    }

    .green & {
        background: green;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there some way I can do a statement like this. If the class on the HTML element is "color-scheme-1", then $accent: orange. If the class on the HTML element is "color-scheme-2", then $accent: green?

Comment: You can set a variable wherever you want.  Based on how it sounds like you want to use the variable, you won't get the results you're looking for.  Please update your question with a clearer picture of what you're trying to do.  Variables aren't the way to go for your simple example.

Comment: I've asked a new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14552529/dynamic-sass-variables/14552770#comment20302176_14552770

Comment: It would have been more appropriate to update your existing question, rather than creating a new one that is virtually identical.  Opening questions and not accepting answers hurts your rating and makes people less likely to help you in the future.

Comment: Ok sorry, I thought it would be better to leave the question there for other people, since your answer might solve the problem to an acceptable standard for them. I'll upvote on that basis. Thanks.