# Dynamic Sass Variables

Tags: css, sass

Is there any way I can set my color variables depending on what class is on the html element? Or any other way to achieve this same goal?

```
html {

  &.sunrise {
    $accent: #37CCBD;
    $base: #3E4653;
    $flat: #eceef1;
  }

  &.moonlight {
    $accent: #18c;
    $base: #2a2a2a;
    $flat: #f0f0f0;
  }

}
```

Comment: You could use LESS, which can be set up to compile client-side and works in a similar fashion. This may have performance implications, however. http://lesscss.org/

Comment: @colmtuite what you have done to fix this? I am stuck with the same issue.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is basic theming.  You would either want to use a mixin or include to do multiple themes in a single CSS file.  This is how you would go about it using includes:

_theme.scss

```
section.accent {
    background: $accent;
}

.foo {
    border: $base;
}

.bar {
    color: $flat;
}
```

main.scss

```
html {
  &.sunrise {
    $accent: #37CCBD;
    $base: #3E4653;
    $flat: #eceef1;

    @import "theme";
  }

  &.moonlight {
    $accent: #18c;
    $base: #2a2a2a;
    $flat: #f0f0f0;

    @import "theme";
 }
}
```

You could just as easily make a mixin that takes 3 colors as its arguments to use in place of the include:

```
@mixin theme($accent, $base, $flat) {
    // .. do stuff ..
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, *Sass/Scss* files need to get compiled into *Css* files, in order to be supported in your web-browser.

Since *Css* files don't support variables, you can only set a variables value in the *Scss* template, because the *Sass* compiler will replace the var. (in every position, the var. has been used), with the given value.

That means, that it does not help to change the color of the variable, depending on what class is included in the *Html* file, because the *Css* file won't contain any variables.

The only way you could do such thing, is by:

1. reading the *Html* file to find out what class has been used,
2. than changing the *Scss* template variables to the right color value
3. and compiling the *Scss* template into an *Css* file

Comment: Yeah, the problem is, I need this to work. Is there absolutely no way? Even with JS?

Comment: Oh I am sorry. i forgot. Of course, you can use just JavaScript to do such job, but than it doesn't matter if u use Scss or regular CSS. wait, i am gonna post you how to do it with JS. :)

Comment: Never mind, just use the "Less" thing. it seems to be easier. :)

Comment: I think I'd prefer the JS option, if you have time? My entire project uses Sass, don't really want to get into Less.

Comment: Sure, lets see, what i can do

Answer (score -3):

If you like to use JavaScript, you can do this:

You will need an HTML element with an Id and a Class (the one that will decides, what color to use).

```
<exampleTagg id="Target" class="Sunrise">...</exampleTagg>
```

Next, you will need to add some JavaSript

```
var CurrentColor = document.getElementById("Target").className; 

if (CurrentColor == "sunrise") {
  document.exampleTagg.style.exampleProperty = "#37CCBD";
}
else if (CurrentColor == "moonlight") {
  document.exampleTagg.style.exampleProperty = "#18c";
}
```

(the first line will declare a variable, that contains the value of our exampleTagg element (the one with the "Target" id), then the if statement will find out the name of our class (sunrise or moonlight) and last, we will change the background of our exampleTagg to the color we like to)

To use this example for your own purposes, replace the exampleTagg with some real tagg and change the exampleProperty to an valid Css property.

Notice, that you will not need Scss for this job (u can still use it), because JavaScript will access your compiled Css file.

Comment: Ups, the "..." should be replaced with <exampleTagg id="Target" class="sunrise">...</exampleTagg>

Comment: I misunderstood. I thought I could use JS to alter the Sass variable. These variables will be occurring in hundreds of places in my app. It's not feasible to edit them individually. I need some way to access the Sass variables and edit them. Is this completely impossible, by any method?

Comment: Oh, if you gonna use this Lesscss thing, u should actually accept the other answer, because it provides "the best" answer to the question. but thanks for accepting my answer. :) (i just think it would be unfair)