# Override SASS variable inside of a selector

Tags: sass

I'm trying to override the value of a variable when the body has a specific class on it. I'm hoping to be able to change to different 'themes' based on this class that I add to the body.

A default variable for my primary color

```
$primary: #6cc907;
```

Override the primary variable

```
.branded {
  $primary: #e43e94;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic Sass Variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14552529/dynamic-sass-variables)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider using a `mixin` instead of a variable for this application. In your selector, you can include the `mixin` and pass it a variable. You can even set a default value for the `mixin` variable, in this case your base `background-color`. Override it by passing the `mixin` a new value.

**Sass**

```
@mixin bg-color($primary: #6cc907) {
  background-color: $primary;
}

div {
  @include bg-color(); // Use default value

  display: inline-block;
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;

  &.branded {
    @include bg-color(#e43e94); // Override value
  }
}
```

[Codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vgyrx)