# Is it possible to define and overwrite Sass/SCSS variables based on conditions

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, scss-mixins

I have an I have a `_overrides.scss` file in which I want to provide a global variable based on conditions.

The variable should be `true` if my navigation with the `.side-navigation` class also contains the `.-open` class. If it contains the `-closed` class, the variable should have the value `false`.

Something like this:

```
$navbarOpen: false;

.side-navigation {
  &.-open {
    $navbarOpen: true;
  }
  &.-closed {
    $navbarOpen: false;
  }
}
```

I want to use the variable within another SCSS module in React, like:

```
@import 'overrides';

@if $navbarOpen == true {
  footer {
    background: red;
  }
}
```

The variable is recognized, but the value is always `false` since it doesn't seem to be overridden by the condition set in `_overrides.scss`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19039622/override-sass-variable-inside-of-a-selector

Comment: Thanks for the link but how can I apply this to my use case?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that Sass variables can't be changed in the runtime, it'll be compiled to plain CSS and all vars will be replaced. Although as I see your condition depends on runtime events.

Check this for references: [Dynamic Sass Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14552529/4423681)