# Checking of body class in sass

Tags: sass

I have defined a variable in sass i.e $title-color: red now I want to change it to based on the class of body e.g on home page body is having class .home so color of all header elements should be for red and if it body is having class .about then that variable should be having green color.

How can I achieve this in SASS.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14552529/dynamic-sass-variables

Answer (score 12):

You can also put an ampersand **after** a class in sass

```
$background-default: white;
$background-dark: black;
$background-yellow: yellow;

.card {
  background: $background-default;

  body.theme-dark & {
    background: $background-dark;
  }

  body.theme-yellow & {
    background: $background-yellow;
  }
}
```

will render to css

```
.card {
  background: white;
}

body.theme-dark .card {
  background: black;
}

body.theme-yellow .card {
  background: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend creating two different variables :

```
$color-red: red;
$color-green: green;

$color-title-primary: $color-red;
$color-title-secondary: $color-green;
```

Then in your file :

```
body {
  &.home {
    h1,
    h2, 
    h3 {
      color: $color-title-primary;
    }
  &.about {
    h1,
    h2,
    h3 {
      color: $color-title-secondary;
    }
  }
}
```

There are probably other solutions but I think this is easy to understand and maintain this way :)